# AWS S3 Bucket setup for durability/integrity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is a bit generic, but I was wondering, is there a specific bucket setup that provides better durability for the data hosted in the case of technical failures of the specific data center location or regardless of which data center location and storage class are chosen, Amazon ensures the durability/integrity of customers data in case of a technical failure? Is there a need for multi-region replication for the sake of receiving better protection against data loss or that's something used purely for compliance/latency purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 provides [99.999999999% durability](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/DataDurability.html) which is more then enough for most scenarios. But if you want even better protection of your data, you have [S3 replication](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/replication/) to different region or even different region.

Replication is not only used for  compliance/latency. It is used for backup as well for most critical data that can't be lost in an unlikely situation of entire AWS region failure, e.g. due to massive earthquake.